# What does it mean when a ram chip has DDR3L and PC3L properties and vice versa?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I wish to buy a new ram for my laptop. Upon examining my laptop specs, I saw that it is using a DDR3L ram already.

After browsing for suitable alternatives, I narrowed it down to [this](https://www.amazon.in/Samsung-original-204-pin-PC3L-12800-1600MHz/dp/B00I21G832/ref=sr_1_5?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1527317764&sr=1-5&keywords=8gb%20ram&refinements=p_n_style_browse-bin%3A1464327031) and [this](https://www.amazon.in/Crucial-Technology-PC3-12800-SODIMM-Laptop/dp/B008LTBLLY/ref=sr_1_12?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1527317764&sr=1-12&keywords=8gb%20ram&refinements=p_n_style_browse-bin%3A1464327031) as my possible options. I am concerned that the first one is DDR3 with PC3L while the second one is DDR3L with PC3. This has gotten me confused.

Upon googling up these terms I found that:
*"PC3 or DDR3 is the operated at 1.50v whereas PC3L or DDR3L is the Low Voltage memory module that operates at 1.35V."* This makes it look like the two terms mean the same thing. But then in the description of the two items, they do not match and this has got me confused.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: All I know is that I never have any spare...

Comment: When in doubt use [System Scanner from Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner?cm_re=us-top-nav-_-us-flyout-upgrades-_-us-upgrades-scanner).

Comment: It means someone flubbed the product description. Alternatively, it means "DDR3" is a valid way of describing DDR3L. Look up the model number on the manufacturer's website for definitive specs.

Answer (score 1):

[Your first 'this'](https://www.amazon.in/Samsung-original-204-pin-PC3L-12800-1600MHz/dp/B00I21G832/ref=sr_1_5?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1527317764&sr=1-5&keywords=8gb%20ram&refinements=p_n_style_browse-bin%3A1464327031)

When you scroll down to the Technical Details, under Voltage, it states 1.35V. The naming is a bit complicated, but the Voltage is 'L' compatible.

DDR3 and DDR3L RAM are almost identical, save for the physical and logical size and voltage requirements.

*Both of your memory chips will work, I just linked the first one to demonstrate*

Comment: The memory chips have different dimensions. I don't think both will work then will it? I have a Dell Inspirion 7559. Which one do you think would be appropriate for this?

Answer (score 0):

from the Dell web site:  https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln153768/what-is-ddr3l-memory?lang=en

looks like they are different ways of saying the same thing.  Assuming it applies to other manufacturers as well...

Answer (score 0):

What i knew is that ddr3 is 1.5 and ddr3L is 1.35 but can work with 1.5 system.
With this If your laptop originally has a ddr3L, DDR3 might not work since we can say that the system is working with a 1.35v for memory and with this, you might have a problem with ddr3 sinceddr3 is rated at 1.5 volts.

On the other hand, if your laptop has an original RAM of ddr3, DDR3L will work because of the capability of ddr3l to work with 1.35 and 1.5v which explains a laptop that has an original of ddr3 before and switched to ddr3L.
hope this help.....